# can't find php.ini in the etc folder?

Tags: root, php

I have root access to my dedicated server, and when I run `phpinfo()` it says my php.ini file is in the etc/ directory, using ssh i can't seem to find it there, i don't know where i can find it thanks :))

Comment: try running 'locate php.ini' or if that doesn't work, 'slocate php.ini'

Comment: it says cnt find command `slocate` or `locate`

Comment: don't look at `Configuration File (php.ini) Path` which shows where ini file should be, but at `Loaded Configuration File`, if it shows `none`, there was no ini file in expected location.

Comment: what operating system / distro are you running?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This may not be a question for SO, but here's a couple potential solutions, all depending on your distro of course:

```
locate php.ini
```

Should give you the directory that php.ini resides in (You may need to do updatedb first)

Otherwise, there's always find.

```
find / -name "php.ini"
```

Comment: the above find cmd returns the path '/etc/php.ini', its readable from terminal but not visible when loggedin via ssh. can any one tell why?

Answer (score 4):

As described in the [PEAR installation manual](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.checking.php), you can discover the ini files that PHP uses by running

```
$ php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php/cli-php5
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php/cli-php5/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php/cli-php5/ext-active
Additional .ini files parsed:      /etc/php/cli-php5/ext-active/php_gtk2.ini,
                                   /etc/php/cli-php5/ext-active/xdebug.ini
```

Answer (score 1):

a quick command to see which php.ini file you're using via command line / terminal

```
php -i | grep /php.ini
```

or

```
php --ini | grep /php.ini
```